# SQL Server CLR UDF time-out

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I have the following setup in SQL Server 2008 R2: A view that uses cross apply on a table-valued user-defined funtion which calls a CLR method. This CLR method converts a given BLOB to a table containing doubles.

Occasionally some queries using the view times-out after around 10 seconds. The time-out does not happen consistently for any query, and when some query fails, other queries work just fine. These queries have the same structure but query different data.

No error is logged in the SQL Server Log when the problem occurs. I suspect that the time-out is related to the use of CLR but have no observation to actually verify this.

Any suggestions for further troubleshooting would be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here is the C# code:

```
private class Row
{
    public SqlDateTime TimeStep { get; set; }
    public SqlDouble Amount { get; set; }
}

public static void TableUDF_FillRow(object tableTypeObject, out SqlDateTime timeStep, out SqlDouble amount)
{
    Row tableType = (Row)tableTypeObject;
    timeStep = tableType.TimeStep;
    amount = tableType.Amount;
}

[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
             TableDefinition = "timeStep DATETIME, amount FLOAT",
             FillRowMethodName = "TableUDF_FillRow")]
public static IEnumerable VarBinaryToFloatTable(byte[] blob, DateTime simulationStartDate)
{
    double[] result = new double[blob.Length / sizeof(double)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(blob, 0, result, 0, blob.Length);

    var list = new List<Row>(result.Length);
    foreach (double d in result)
    {
        Row row = new Row
        {
            TimeStep = simulationStartDate, 
            Amount = d
        };
        list.Add(row);
        simulationStartDate = simulationStartDate.AddHours(1); // assumes one hour time steps
    }

    return list;
}
```

The table-valued UDF just calls the VarBinaryToFloatTable() method.

Comment: Have you tried removing the SQLCLR TVF to see if it still happens? How does it timeout after 10 seconds? The default CommandTimeout for a query is 30 seconds, and the default ConnectionTimeout is 15 seconds. But both are configurable so someone could have set a lower value. Can you post any of the SQLCLR code to see if there are any ineffeciencies there? Is it doing any data access via `SqlConnection`? Why do you suspect the SQLCLR TVF as being the source of the timeout? Select from `sys.dm_exec_requests` and when you see that view (might need to check a diff DMV for it) look at the wait_type.

Comment: @srutzky: Thanks for all the suggestions, which helped me solve the problem. The time-out was caused by a low threshold in the client code (VBA in Excel). The SQLCLR code does not use a SqlConnection but is quite slow, since it converts a large BLOB. The main problem was that a lot of BLOBs were converted by the SQLCLR before being filtered away in a join. Adding a where clause in order to avoid unnecessary conversions improved performance significantly.

Comment: Glad it helped. It is possible that you could still improve the efficiency of that SQLCLR UDF. I am curious as to why it is slow, but can't offer any advice without seeing the code itself.